# nginx rewrite any sub-domain to specific URL

Tags: redirect, nginx

I want to redirect the url for the following scenario in **Nginx**.

My domain name  `*.xyz.com`

If the user send the request from 
  `reuest url  -> abc.xyz.com`

`abc` is not constant name.

`Xyz.com` is my domain and anything before the `.xyz.com` is redirecting to `xyz.com/<abc>` in the backend

In the backend request goes to 
`abc.xyz.com` to `xyz.com/<abc>`

But in the browser Url will be same.
i.e. `abc.xyz.com`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression for your server_name and store the subdomain in a named capture. Then have a variable root:

```
server {
    server_name  ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.xyz\.com$;
    root /var/www/$subdomain;
}
```